# PanResponder with SignatureScreen not working

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview, panresponder

**Objective**: I am trying to use `SignatureScreen` from `react-native-signature-canvas` inside a `ScrollView`. But whenever I try to scroll up and down. `ScrollView` takes the gesture and moves the screen instead of focusing on `SignatureScreen`.

I found the solution of using `PanResponder` as a wrapper on SignatureScreen to avoid the parent view getting the gesture event.

Following is the Pandresponder code:

```
PanResponder.create({
      // Ask to be the responder:
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) =>
        true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) =>
        true,

      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The gesture has started. Show visual feedback so the user knows
        // what is happening!
        // gestureState.d{x,y} will be set to zero now
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The most recent move distance is gestureState.move{X,Y}
        // The accumulated gesture distance since becoming responder is
        // gestureState.d{x,y}
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) =>
        true,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The user has released all touches while this view is the
        // responder. This typically means a gesture has succeeded
      },
      onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // Another component has become the responder, so this gesture
        // should be cancelled
      },
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // Returns whether this component should block native components from becoming the JS
        // responder. Returns true by default. Is currently only supported on android.
        return true;
      }
    })
  ).current;
```

Following is the render code:

```
  <ScrollView>
    <View
      style={styles.signatureContainerStyle}
      {...panResponder.panHandlers}
    >
      <SignatureScreen
        ref={ref}
        onOK={onSignatureUpdate}
        onEnd={handleOnEndCallback} // Mandatory to trigger onOk on its own
        descriptionText={labelText}
        backgroundColor={CORE_COLORS.components.signature.background}
        webStyle={canvasStyle}
        webviewContainerStyle={{ opacity: 0.99 }}
        onBegin={handleOnFocus}
        dataURL={initialValue}
      />
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
```

This solution was working perfectly on `iOS` as the `ScrollView` did not get any gesture while drawing on `SignatureScreen`. However, on `Android`, `SignatureScreen` was also not getting the gesture. While the expected behaviour on android was like iOS, that `SignatureScreen` gets gesture and not the `ScrollView` while drawing.

**Here is what I found:**
`onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture` and `onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture` should return `false`, if we want the child to listen to gestures.

and we should use `event.stopPropagation()` and set the `onPanResponderTerminationRequeston` to return `false` to stop the gesture event to propagate to the parent view. So here is what my updated code looks like:

```
  const panResponder = React.useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      // Ask to be the responder:
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => false,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => false,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => false,

      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The gesture has started. Show visual feedback so the user knows
        // what is happening!
        // gestureState.d{x,y} will be set to zero now
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The most recent move distance is gestureState.move{X,Y}
        // The accumulated gesture distance since becoming responder is
        // gestureState.d{x,y}
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => false,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The user has released all touches while this view is the
        // responder. This typically means a gesture has succeeded
      },
      onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // Another component has become the responder, so this gesture
        // should be cancelled
      },
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // Returns whether this component should block native components from becoming the JS
        // responder. Returns true by default. Is currently only supported on android.
        return true;
      },
    })
  ).current;
```

But the issue is still the same, on Android phones, the child component is not getting the gesture. It only draws a single dot and that's it.

Following are the versions:

- "react-native": "0.69.4",
- "react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.3.0",
- "react-native-webview": "11.23.0",